# Popup Force Browser Open Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm building a mobile app website, but I have a really broad question which I'm not sure will be even possible to answer.

The web app website I'm building lets users submit data over the day, every 20 minutes or so it syncs their information to a server which can take upwards of 10 minutes with a poor signal.

What I don't want to happen is for the user to leave while the sync is in process - even though their data will still be ready for upload again, when they come back it would cost them unnecessary upload bandwidth on their tariff.

Basically I have some code which displays a loader but I don't think this is enough.

```
   $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
         $('.spinner').show();
   });
```

Would there be any way to force the user to keep on the browser, or page open until the ajax has stopped? Like a force popup - I know it seems annoying but it's in the best interest of the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not display a spinning logo while it's syncing. You could have it load at the start of the function then disable it on the callback. It's not going to force anything but it will be visually obvious to the user that something is happening.

Comment: I have already got a spinner going, but I dont think its enough I would like to make sure they dont leave by forcing some sort of popup until ajax stops

Comment: the window.onunload probably won't work (and it's not even supported by all browsers) you might be better off storing some of the data locally (perhaps in a cookie) and then clearing the cookie if the ajax call is successful.

Comment: This is also what I'm doing, but I wouldn't like them to try uploading twice if the close

Comment: For the double upload, you could probably use some sort of pre-check to see if the data has been uploaded previously or not. It wouldn't have to be as big as the full upload, perhaps just a hash.

Comment: I'll up vote you anyway for your time, thanks for ideas